# can we pass variables to file arguments in python? If yes whats the syntax?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a variable that picks up values dynamically. Now I want to pass the value of this variable to a python file as an argument. How can I do this?

While executing the command line arguments in python notebook as

`!python <filename.py> --<arg1> <varname>`
the variable name gets attached to the path instead of the value of the varaiable.

The error I get is

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'varname'
>   ​

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Look at the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html) module for some more insight